# React hook form and zod inumber input

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, zod

I have created a form with react hook form and did a validation with zod. In one input I want to write in numbers, when I write any number, the error says it is not a number:

```
<Controller
          name="calories"
          control={control}
          defaultValue={1}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <input
              {...field}
              type="number"
              className="w-full px-3 py-2 border rounded-md"
            />
          )}
```

```
 calories: z
    .number({
      required_error: "Calories is required",
      invalid_type_error: "Calories must be a number",
    })
    .int()
    .positive()
    .min(1, { message: "Calories should be at least 1" }),
```

I am missing something?

Did not find any solution to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution that was given from Ahmed Sbai from [here](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/discussions/330)
End solution is this:

```
calories: z.preprocess(
(a) => parseInt(z.string().parse(a), 10),
z.number().positive().min(1)
),
```

Answer (score 5):

what you want is:

```
 calories: z.coerce
    .number({
      required_error: "Calories is required",
      invalid_type_error: "Calories must be a number",
    })
    .int()
    .positive()
    .min(1, { message: "Calories should be at least 1" }),
```

note the `coerce` before the `.number()`. It will take whatever it is inputted, i.e.: the string `'42'` and will cast it to the number `42`.

Answer (score 3):

With react-hook-form you can convert the string value to a number like this:

```
    <input
      {...register('numberInput', {
        setValueAs: (value) => Number(value),
      })}
      type="number"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

When the input is of type `number`, it sends its value as a `string` even if the user inputs a number.
 As a result, Zod sees the value as a `string` and considers it invalid for the `number()` validation.

I am not familiar with Zod but the idea here is that before applying the Zod validation, if you can, you'll need to convert the input value to a number otherwise validate it as a string that should be a valid number have a look [here](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/discussions/330)

Answer (score 0):

You can also add to your Controller the rules argument and add `valueAsNumber:true` to it. You can check more details [here](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/usecontroller/controller)

Comment: `valueAsNumber` is only available for `register` function, not in `controller` or `useController`